# What does the -1 mean in tensor.size(-1)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have seen something like this in the Pytorch documentation,

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([1, 2])
a.size() # torch.Size([2])
a.size(-1) # 2
```

How does this work? I didn't find a description. Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

`a.size(-1)` refers to the last dimension. For example, if the shape of x were (10,20) then x.size(-1) refers to second dimension i.e. 20.
Take a look at the following examples:

```
import torch
a= torch.zeros((2,5)) # a is matrix of 2 rows and 5 columns all elements are 0
#size gives a 1d tensor containing the shapes
a.size(-1)# refers to the last element in the tensor
```

This is equivalent to:

```
a_size= a.size()
a_size(-1)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think you can say the .size() function returns a list of the dimensions and so, -1 index means the first element from the end, as it does in normal Python.

Comment: @akshayk07 That would be the case if the code was `t.size()[-1]`. But `t.size(-1)` isn’t the same (although it happens to have the same effect).

Comment: I understand the result, but still don't know where the syntax is from. a.size() returns a torch.Size object which is not callable, so a_size(-1) will raise an error. @KonradRudolph